# Show time with a 0 in front of it if it is less than 10

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Time extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeState createState() => _TimeState();
}

class _TimeState extends State<Time> {
  String time = "Press Button to see time";
  bool isSelected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TimeOfDay startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 01, minute: 00);
    final endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59);
    final step = Duration(minutes: 5);

    Iterable<TimeOfDay> getTimes(
        TimeOfDay startTime, TimeOfDay endTime, Duration step) sync* {
      var hour = startTime.hour;
      var minute = startTime.minute;

      do {
        yield TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
        minute += step.inMinutes;
        while (minute >= 60) {
          minute -= 60;
          hour++;
        }
      } while (hour < endTime.hour ||
          (hour == endTime.hour && minute <= endTime.minute));
    }

    final times = getTimes(startTime, endTime, step)
        .where((t) =>
            t.minute >= TimeOfDay.now().minute &&
            t.hour >= TimeOfDay.now().hour)
        .map((tod) => tod.format(context));

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: times
                .map<Widget>(
                  (t) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        isSelected = !isSelected;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: isSelected ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white,
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.deepOrange,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            10.0,
                          ),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: isSelected ? Colors.black26 : Colors.white,
                              blurRadius: 5,
                              offset: Offset(2, 2),
                            )
                          ]),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        t,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.deepOrange,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I wanted to ask, Currently if the time is under 10 let's say 9:30. It is showing it as it is not as 09:30 which is what I'm looking for. Can you please tell me how to do it. Also if I tap on any one of the containers, all of them get selected. how do I get it such that only the container that user press on gets selected. And how do I know which one the user has selected Can you please Help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently if the time is under 10 let's say 9:30. It is showing it as it is not as 09:30 which is what I'm looking for.

Try changing

```dart
.map((tod) => tod.format(context));
```

to

```dart
.map((tod) => "${tod.hour}".padLeft(2, '0') + ':' + "${tod.minute}".padLeft(2, '0'));
// Pad '0' left to the hours and minutes until both has two characters and join with ':'
```

If you want to rely on `tod.format(context)` implementation, you can also try

```dart
.map((tod) => tod.format(context).padLeft(5, '0'));
// If it returns "5:40", pad '0' left until this string has five characters ("05:40")
```

---

> Also if I tap on any one of the containers, all of them get selected. how do i get it such that only the container that i press on gets selected.

You can replace `isSelected` with a list that keeps track of which containers are selected:

```dart
List<bool> selectedTimes;
```

Every time you set `times`, also set `selectedTimes`:

```dart
final times = getTimes(startTime, endTime, step)
    .where((t) =>
        t.minute >= TimeOfDay.now().minute &&
        t.hour >= TimeOfDay.now().hour)
    .map((tod) => tod.format(context));

// Start all containers unselected
selectedTimes = times.map((t) => false).toList();
```

Then, where you were using `isSelected`, replace by getting the respective time index in `selectedTimes`. You can do this by creating a new method where you return a new `Container`:

```dart
Widget buildTimeTile(BuildContext context, List<String> times, int i) {
  final t = times[i];
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        selectedTimes[i] = !selectedTimes[i];
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      // ...
    )
  );
}
```

Now, where you were creating the `Container`, replace by the method call using a `for` loop:

```dart
Wrap(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++)
      buildTimeTile(context, times, i)
  ]
);
```

**Full code:**

```dart
class Time extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimeState createState() => _TimeState();
}

class _TimeState extends State<Time> {
  List<String> times;
  List<bool> selectedTimes;
  String time = "Press Button to see time";
  
  void initTimes() {
    TimeOfDay startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 00, minute: 00);
    final endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59);
    final step = Duration(minutes: 5);
   
    times = getTimes(startTime, endTime, step)
        .where((t) =>
            t.hour > TimeOfDay.now().hour ||
            (t.hour >= TimeOfDay.now().hour &&
                t.minute > TimeOfDay.now().minute))
        .map((tod) => tod.format(context).padLeft(8, '0'),)
        .toList();
   
    selectedTimes = times.map((t) => false).toList();
  }
 
  Iterable<TimeOfDay> getTimes(
    TimeOfDay startTime, TimeOfDay endTime, Duration step) sync* {
      var hour = startTime.hour;
      var minute = startTime.minute;

      do {
        yield TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
        minute += step.inMinutes;
        while (minute >= 60) {
          minute -= 60;
          hour++;
        }
      } while (hour < endTime.hour ||
          (hour == endTime.hour && minute <= endTime.minute));
    }
 
  Widget buildTimeTile(BuildContext context, int i) {
      final t = times[i];
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selectedTimes[i] = !selectedTimes[i];
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(7.5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: selectedTimes[i] ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
              width: 1,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
              10.0,
            ),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Text(
            t,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: selectedTimes[i] ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (times == null) initTimes();
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < times.length; i++) buildTimeTile(context, i)
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Could you also look into the second part of the problem? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer. See if this solves your problem.

Comment: Ok so it works kind of I mean it is showing me the time which I have selected as I print it out into console. also it is updating the selectedtimes list but, the problem is that it is not showing any updates in the UI. Could you tell me your email or anything where I can reach you and send this updated code so you could look for problems.

Comment: Either way, I've added the full code to the answer if it helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: The full code seems to have the same problem i mentioned. It is not updating in UI. I mailed you my code at the mail you asked

Comment: I've replied to you and updated my full code here.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes. This should work perfectly. Thanks @Chris for the guidance

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Time extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TimeState createState() => _TimeState();
}

class _TimeState extends State<Time> {
  String time = "Press Button to see time";
  String _selectedTime;  // ADDED VARIABLE TO SAVE SELECTED TIME
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TimeOfDay startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 01, minute: 00);
    final endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 59);
    final step = Duration(minutes: 5);

    String _time(int digit) {
      if(digit < 10) {
        return '0$digit';
      } else {
        return '$digit';
      }
    }

    Iterable<TimeOfDay> getTimes(
        TimeOfDay startTime, TimeOfDay endTime, Duration step) sync* {
      var hour = startTime.hour;
      var minute = startTime.minute;

      do {
        yield TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
        minute += step.inMinutes;
        while (minute >= 60) {
          minute -= 60;
          hour++;
        }
      } while (hour < endTime.hour ||
          (hour == endTime.hour && minute <= endTime.minute));
    }

    final times = getTimes(startTime, endTime, step)
        .where((t) {
      return (t.hour <= TimeOfDay.now().hour
        ? t.minute >= TimeOfDay.now().minute
        : t.minute == t.minute)
      && t.hour >= TimeOfDay.now().hour;
    }
    ).map((tod)  {return '${_time(tod.hour)}:${_time(tod.minute)} ${tod.hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM" }'; });

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: times
                .map<Widget>(
                  (t) => GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedTime = t;
                  });
                },
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: t == _selectedTime ? Colors.deepOrange : Colors.white,  // CHANGED HERE
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.deepOrange,
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        10.0,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: t == _selectedTime ? Colors.black26 : Colors.white,  // CHANGED HERE
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          offset: Offset(2, 2),
                        )
                      ]),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Text(
                    t,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: t == _selectedTime ? Colors.white : Colors.deepOrange,  // CHANGED HERE
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );  }
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].